# Find the coefficient of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

$y(t) = x''(t) + c_1x'(t) + c_0x(t)$

Determine the coefficients $c_1$ And $c_0$ so that the output signal become $y(t) = 0$ when the input signal is $x(t) = sin(w_0t)$ for some given constant $w_0$.

Comment: Do you know the equation of the harmonic oscillator?

Comment: @Adam. You wrote : $$y(t) = x''(t) + c_1x'(t) + c_0x'(t)$$ Why don't you wrote : $$y(t) = x''(t) + (c_1+c_0)x'(t)$$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin ahh i did a mistake the last term should be $c_0x(t)$ thanks for this i will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y(t) = x''(t) + c_1x'(t) + c_0x(t)$$
If $x(t)=\sin(\omega t)$
$$y(t) = -\omega^2\sin(t) +c_1\omega \cos(t) + c_0\sin(t)$$
$$y(t) = (c_0-\omega^2)\sin(t) +c_1\omega \cos(t) $$
Obviously $y(t)=0$ implies $$c_0=\omega^2 \text{ and } c_1=0$$

Comment: Thanks! can you pleas also have look in next question and give me some tip how to solve it , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2987409/428246

Comment: @Adam. Sorry, the wording of your question isn't clear enough. Define well the variables that you introduce. Better, on a math forum, avoid to use non-mathematical terms such as "input signal", "output signal", "transient exit".